# Line breaking words with apostrophe gets overflows

Tags: pdftex, line-breaking

I'm using [this](http://pastebin.com/fKHtSxmc) Latex document class (that's the class used for the CHI/TEI conferences) and I'm facing a strange problem with automatic newlines with words having apostrophes: in Italian we are used to have words like *l'albero* or *l'informazione*.

Unfortunately, it looks like whenever Latex (pdflatex, most recent texlive) encounter one of those words, it's not able to line break within that word which then overflows the column space.

[image]

Example document showing such problem [here](http://pastebin.com/Dh032sX4).

Any kind of help appreciated.

Comment: If you're already using **babel**, check whether your log file says something about "Italian" and hyphenation patterns; such problems can happen with MiKTeX up to version 2.8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load [babel](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) with the italian option to get proper hyphenation. Load it like `\usepackage[italian]{babel}`

Comment: Thanks.. this fixed the problem in the example I provided. However, when placing a citation with `\cite{sachs01}` I get _Use of \@citex doesn't match its definition_ any idea???

Comment: babel is very picky about when it is loaded with respect to other packages, as is hyperref. You should load babel as early as possible.

Comment: No matter where I place babel, that error is always there. Looks like a conflict with the class I'm using. Any idea??

Comment: I had a look in the class file, I removed the `,` from `{\@tempswafalse\@citex,[]}% was ; Gerry 2/24/00` on line `1349`. Works for me now, not really sure why there would be a `,` there...